# Que veut dire l'expression « à l'heure qu'il est » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, indications-de-temps

Cette expression fait partie d'une phrase suivante, tirée du chapitre 10 de *Harry Potter à l'école des sorciers* :

> S'ils ne m'avaient pas retrouvée, je serais morte à l'heure qu'il est.

Je comprends *Hadn't they found me, I would have been dead*, mais que signifie « à l'heure qu'il est » ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Une meilleure traduction en anglais de ton exemple serait :

> Had they not found me, I would be dead **by now**.

« À l'heure qu'il est » est plus ou moins synonyme de « maintenant », mais est souvent utilisé dans des tournures où une situation hypothétique, virtuelle ou géographiquement disjointe est envisagée :

> Leur avion est parti il y a 5 heures. Ils sont probablement arrivés à destination à l'heure qu'il est.
>
> J'ai complètement oublié de fermer le robinet de ma salle de bains avant de partir ce matin : mon appartement doit être complètement inondé à l'heure qu'il est.

Comment: Rien de plus à ajouter, tout y est ! Le temps d'écrire ce commentaire, Dave devrait avoir +15 à l'heure qu'il est :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse si complète.

Comment: For reference, the actual English text is as follows: _‘If they hadn't found me, I'd be dead now. Harry stuck his wand up its nose and Ron knocked it out with its own club. They didn't have time to come and fetch anyone. It was about to finish me off when they arrived.’_

Answer (score 1):

La traduction littérale de "à l'heure qu'il est" en anglais serait : "at the current hour" et de manière plus jolie et plus usuelle : "by now".

Answer (score -1):

"A l'heure qu'il est" signifie "at this time", version anglaise de "now" abondamment utilisée par les douaniers d'un certain pays, devant les caméras, dans l'émission Border Security: Australia's Front Line.  :-)